# Sensor Data Sampling Frequency Mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have sensor data captured at different frequencies (this is data I've invented to simplify the operation). I want to resample the voltage data by increasing the number of data points and interpolate them so I have 16 instead of 12.

Pandas has a resample/upsample function but I can only find examples where people have gone from weekly data to daily data (adding 6 daily data points by interpolation between two weekly data points).

time (pressure)
0.05
0.1
0.15
0.2
0.25
0.3
0.35
0.4
0.45
0.5
0.55
0.6
0.65
0.7
0.75
0.8

pressure
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5

time (voltage)
0.07
0.14
0.21
0.28
0.35
0.42
0.49
0.56
0.63
0.7
0.77
0.84

voltage
2.2
2.5
2.8
3.1
3.4
3.7
4
4.3
4.6
4.9
5.2
5.5

I would like my voltage to have 16 samples instead of 12 with the missing values interpolated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume two Series, "pressure" and "voltage":

```
pressure = pd.Series({0.05: 1.0, 0.1: 1.1, 0.15: 1.2, 0.2: 1.3, 0.25: 1.4, 0.3: 1.5, 0.35: 1.6, 0.4: 1.7, 0.45: 1.8,
                       0.5: 1.9, 0.55: 2.0, 0.6: 2.1, 0.65: 2.2, 0.7: 2.3, 0.75: 2.4, 0.8: 2.5}, name='pressure')
voltage = pd.Series({0.07: 2.2,  0.14: 2.5,  0.21: 2.8,  0.28: 3.1,  0.35: 3.4,  0.42: 3.7,
                     0.49: 4.0,  0.56: 4.3,  0.63: 4.6,  0.7: 4.9,  0.77: 5.2,  0.84: 5.5}, name='voltage')
```

You can either use `pandas.merge_asof`:

```
pd.merge_asof(pressure, voltage, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

output:

[image: merge_asof]

or `pandas.concat`+`interpolate`:

```
(pd.concat([pressure, voltage], axis=1)
   .sort_index()
   .apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
   #.plot(x='pressure', y='voltage', marker='o') # uncomment to plot
)
```

output:

[image: concat+interpolate]

Finally, to interpolate only on voltage, drop NAs on pressure first:

```
(pd.concat([pressure, voltage], axis=1)
   .sort_index()
   .dropna(subset=['pressure'])
   .apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
)
```

output:

[image: concat interpolate alternative]